# Cross Page Master Detail WebPart

Tags: connected-web-parts

I have a custom webpart that either shows a list of products or the detailed view of a single product depending on the configuration options. On the landing page (/Home.aspx) I have the list view on the right column with some general content in the central column. When you click a product I want it to go to the product page (/Product.aspx) where the right column still has a list of items but the central column has the detailed view of the product selected.

I have this working without a problem when you click a product in the list while on the Product.aspx page but I can't get it to work when clicking a product from Home.aspx.

I know cross page PostBacks aren't available in Visual Web Parts. Is it possible to do this without using session state or a query string?

Thanks

Comment: Here are some helpful details on creating master-detail forms in SharePoint.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140095/how-can-lists-be-made-to-support-master-detail-relationships

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to make master/detail web-part there are two way One is OOTB

Option 1: You can connect two web parts for more information I am giving you some links for it

- http://www.simego.com/Blog/2010/12/quickly-create-master-detail-view-on-sharepoint-wss
- http://howididit-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/12/master-detail-in-sharepoint-22.html
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexma/archive/2006/04/10/610934.aspx

Option 2: If you are comfortable with jQuery then use spservices and datatable plugin, I will recommended second option if you want custom web part, and I did it recently in my project. Links for example for datatables. Use spservices as datasource and build drill down as per below link

- http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows

If you still need more info let me know I can provide you.